# Does existence of anti-derivative imply integrability?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ has an anti-derivative in $[a,b]$ does it imply that $f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$?

Comment: Integrable in what sense?

Comment: Normally, this is the case (for regular differentiability of functions $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ and both Riemann and Lebesgue integrals). Do you have any specific integral in mind?

Comment: It is true for Henstock-Kurzweil integral (in this sense H-K integral is better than Riemann and Lebesgue integrals)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin (1/x^2), &x\ne 0, \\ 0, &x=0. \end{cases}\quad$ Then $g=f'$ exists everywhere but is unbounded over $[-1,1]$. $g$ thus has a primitive but is not Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 20):

The function $f$ need not be Riemann integrable over **any** non-trivial interval! It can be even arranged that $f$ is bounded. See [Volterra's Function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function)