# Is this theorem about integration with substitution wrong?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, continuity

A theorem in my book states:

> If $g$ is differentiable, f is continuous, and F is an antiderivative
>   of f, then :
>
> $\int f[g(x)]g'(x)dx=F[g(x)]+C$

The reason I am asking if this is correct, is that the analouge theorem on wikipedia states that g has to be continuously differentiable, that is $g'(x)$ has to be continuous. So is the stated theorem correct or wrong?

PS: On wikipedia, they have inserted limits, I don't know if that has an effect on the answer? 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable

Comment: The result holds, as stated. With indefinite integrals, it's just the chain rule. For definite integrals, you need some condition to insure that $f(g(x))g'(x)$ is integrable.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidMitra Could it happen that a function that has an antiderivative is not integrable? I know that in the converse case we might get problems: a function can be integrable, but not have an antiderivative. But in our case $f(g(x))g'(x)$ has an antiderivative, can it still not be integrable?

Comment: See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6711/integrability-of-derivatives) for an example of functions $g$ which are everywhere differentiable, but $g'$ is not integrable (on some non-degenerate interval). I'm not sure, though, if $f(g(x))g'(x)$ would always be integrable on (some) $[a,b]$ in your setup (there should be a fairly easy example with $g'$ unbounded).

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks, I searched and found an answer you gave 6.5 years ago also! :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168310/does-existence-of-anti-derivative-imply-integrability Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result, with the indefinite integral, holds. It's almost the chain rule (the hypotheses that $f$ is continuous isn't needed; so, the result seems strange).

For definite integrals, the coresponding result isn't true.  Take $F(x)=x$ and $g$ a differentiable function on $[a,b]$ with $g'$ non-integrable on $[a,b]$ (see, again, the comments above). Then $f(g(x))g'(x)=g'(x)$ isn't integrable on $[a,b]$. So, as mentioned in the comments, some additional hypotheses is needed for the substitution rule for definite integrals. $g'$ being continuous works, but one can get by with weaker hypotheses ($g'$ integrable would suffice).

Comment: Nice that you spotted that f don't have to be continuous!